# How to change "networks to access" setting directly in registry?

Tags: windows, wifi

Because of some hard group policy setting, it is not possible to create a computer-to-computer (ad-hoc) network. So is  there any way to change this setting through registry?
What is the registry key for this setting and how could I find out it?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the registry in these spots, this is where policy information is stored.  I's say network settings would be under HKLM.. somewhere:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
```

you will have to find the exact policy in there and remove it.
Then reboot the PC and make sure its not plugged into the network where the AD is accessible.  Should be ok to plug it in after you login.
You will lose the settings on rebooting whilst connected to the domain.

Comment: I don't have Policies key under CurrentControlSet, and yes I'm the local administrator of the machine.

Comment: Policies only come from GPOs set on OUs in AD.  If this setting is coming from a Computer Policy you can expect it to be there, if it's coming from a User Policy, and if you're logging in as a local (non-AD) user, you can expect it not to be there.  If you're logging in as a Domain user and you change networking settings you can expect your access to Domain resources to be potentially affected.

Comment: what is the name of registry setting? I want to search for it, and in the case that it does not exist, I want to create a new key and change the setting there.